# Django internationalization with i18n: choosing language in template using jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, caching, internationalization

For the internationalization of my django project, I'm using django's i18n, and I love it.

For setting the language in the template, instead of using forms like in this example :

```
  <form action="{{site_url}}i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="" />
    <select name="language">
      {% for language in languages %}
      <option value="{{language.0}}">{{language.1}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
  </form>
```

I would like to use simple plain text links; something like this:

```
{% for language in languages %}
    {% ifnotequal language.0 lang %}
    <a href="{{site_url}}i18n/setlang/" >{{language.1}}</a>{% else %}{{language.1}}
    {% endifnotequal %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

For letting the previous template snippet do his work, I've created the following jQuery function:

```
var languageLink = $('#language-choser > a');

languageLink.click(function(e){
  var languageURL = languageLink.attr('href');
  var languageNow = languageLink.text();
  var lang = (languageNow=='English') ? 'en' : 'es';
  $.post(languageURL, {next: "", language:lang});
});
```

This function works with Firefox but not with Chrome: it will simply reload the page, without changing the language.

Someone can tell me what's wrong? I've been playing around with it for a long time, without finding a way out.

**EDIT**
Looks that it could be a **caching** problem. In my click function, I should clean the cached page. But how? Or should I disable browser caching for the whole site? I don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a debug statement (`console.log()`, or even a simple `alert()` will do) at the beginning of the handler function to make sure that it is being invoked at all. Are you adding the click handler in a `document.ready()` handler?

Also I think the `$.post` function will do an AJAX POST, but will not refresh the page, so you may not see anything happening at all. Try using Firebug / Chrome developer tools to examine outgoing requests to make sure.

You may want to make the `click()` handler explicitly return a value too (true means continue processing the click, false means stop). Maybe that's the root of the problem: in Firefox the handler sometimes returns `true`, so the link is followed, while on Chrome it returns `false` and the POST is executed, but the link is not followed.

Comment: Yes, the click handler is in document.ready() handler. I'm using Firebug and DevTools, and I've tried to add some logs: looks that the function is invoked and runs until his end, with the right variable values. After the click, the page does refresh, in the chosen language with Firefox, but with Chrome is in same language as before.